# Sparse clustering using the sparcl package in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am using the `sparcl` package written by Witten and Tibshirani based on their paper:

Witten DM and R Tibshirani (2010) A framework for feature selection in clustering. Journal of the American Statistical Association 105(490): 713-726

I look into the example under the function `HierarchicalSparseCluster`:

```
# Generate 2-class data
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(100*50),ncol=50)
y <- c(rep(1,50),rep(2,50))
x[y==1,1:25] <- x[y==1,1:25]+2

# Do tuning parameter selection for sparse hierarchical clustering
perm.out <- HierarchicalSparseCluster.permute(x, wbounds=c(1.5,2:6),nperms=5)

# Perform sparse hierarchical clustering
sparsehc <- HierarchicalSparseCluster(dists=perm.out$dists, wbound=perm.out$bestw, method="complete")
```

Now I check `dim(sparsehc$dists)` and it returns 4950 and 50. From the simulation set-up, we know that `n=100` and `p=50`. Also, according to the manual, the returned value `dists` is a **(n*n)xp** dissimilarity matrix for the data matrix `x`. Obviously the row dimension is not n*n as it should be 100*100=10000 instead of 4950. Did I misunderstand something? Thank you very much!

Comment: `4950+50=5000=100*50` - any chance that you misused your data matrix as dissimilarity matrix? Since you have 5o instances, the maximum dimensionality needed to represent this data set is 50, and that why I guess you get back 4950 and 50.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: thanks! I am confident in the column dimension of 50, but I am curious about the row dimension of 4950. It is supposed to be the number of observations (`n`) squared, where `n` is the row dimension of the data matrix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be the mistake in `sparcl` help page: dimensions of dissimilarity matrix `dist` are `n2`x`p`, where `n2=n*(n-1)/2`. Indeed, we don't need `n`x`n` matrix of distances, but only part of this matrix over the main diagonal.

Sources of `sparcl` support what I said above:

**distfun.R**

```
distfun=function(x){
#if(!is.loaded("distfun")){
#  dyn.load("distfun.so")
#}
n<-nrow(x)
p <- ncol(x)
x[is.na(x)]=0
mode(x)="single"
n2=n*(n-1)/2
junk=.Fortran("distfun",
         x,
        as.integer(n),
       as.integer(p),
       as.integer(n2),
       d=single(n2*p), PACKAGE="sparcl"
)
return(junk$d)
}
```

Here we can see how `n2` is calculated and passed to Fortran function.

**distfun.f**

```
C Output from Public domain Ratfor, version 1.0
      subroutine distfun(x,n,p,n2,d)
      implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
      integer n,p,n2
      real x(n,p),d(n2,p)
      ii=0
      do23000 i=1,n-1
      do23002 ip=i+1,n
      ii=ii+1
      do23004 j=1,p
      d(ii,j)=abs(x(i,j)-x(ip,j))
23004 continue
23005 continue
23002 continue
23003 continue
23000 continue
23001 continue
      return
      end
```

Here for each feature in `dist` matrix there is a column of size `n2` constructed, that holds a sequence of pairwise distances between objects. For example, for `n=4`, `p=2` and `n2=4*3/2=6` the final matrix will be `6x2` and designed like this:

```
    |    1     |     2    |
---------------------------
  1 | d(1,2)_1 | d(1,2)_2 |
  2 | d(1,3)_1 | d(1,3)_2 |
  3 | d(1,4)_1 | d(1,4)_2 |
  4 | d(2,3)_1 | d(2,3)_2 |
  5 | d(2,4)_1 | d(2,4)_2 |
  6 | d(3,4)_1 | d(3,4)_2 |
```

Where, say, `d(2,4)_1` is a distance between 2nd and 4th object for 1st feature.